# when I use negative margin-top on navbar, hover is not working ok

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar with dropdown menu which works ok, but I have lot of empty space above it because of logo on left side (bootstrap unify theme)
[image: header working dropdown]

so I want to margin my navbar menu up 40px.
When I use margin-top: -40px it moves navbar menu up ok, but dropdown menu shows only when I carefuly move mouse at the bottom of menu. If I use margin-top: -50px I lost hover at all
[image]
[image]

code of header looks like this

```
<div class="header" >
<!-- Topbar -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="topbar" >
    <!--logo-->
     <%= link_to image_tag("logo_d_white.png",size: "180x62", :class => "logo" ), root_path %>     
    <!-- logo end -->
       <ul class="loginbar pull-right">
                <li class="hoverSelector">
                    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                    <a>Jazyky/Languages</a>
                    <ul class="languages hoverSelectorBlock">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Slovenský <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">English</a></li>   
                    </ul>
                </li></ul>
</div>
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
        </button>
</div>
<!--  End Topbar -->
<!-- Navbar -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse mega-menu navbar-responsive-collapse">
   <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
                <!-- Home -->
                <%= content_tag(:li, link_to('Úvod', home_url)) %>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Pre Investorov
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="index.html">aaa</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">bbb</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">ccc</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Projekty
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <%= content_tag(:li, link_to('Založiť nový projekt', project_terms_url)) %>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Úspešne ukončené kampane</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            </div>

<!-- End Navbar -->
```

header.css is huge..I am looking for an advice where to look to which class in css to fix this, so my hover will be active on whole text, not just 1mm below text
thanks

adding css for logo:

```
   .header .logo {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 40px;
    min-width: 100px;
    /*display: table-cell;*/
    display: inline-block;
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.header .logo img {
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 20px 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

I had to comment table-cell and change it to inline because table-cell breaks with topbar

adding css for topbar:

```
.header .topbar {
    z-index: 12;
    /*padding: 8px 0;*/
    padding: 8px 0 25px 0;
    position: relative;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .header .topbar {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}

/*languages*/
.header .topbar ul.languages {
    top: 25px;
    left: -5px;
    display: none;
    padding: 4px 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    min-width: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #f0f0f0;
```

Comment: The reason is likely that your logo element is full width, and with the negative margin you have dragged your nav bar _under_ it – so your mouse is actually hovering the logo, and not the nav bar. Adding `position:relative` and a `z-index` should easily fix that.

Comment: I added css for my logo, it already has position relative and z-index but yes when I look in page inspector, it looks that margin-top:-40px  moves text, but div itself points below

Comment: I meant, apply `z-index` to your nav bar.

Comment: ok I have a progress, now it works, but when I hover on topbar which is above navbar and trying to go through menu, when I get with mouse above navbar, topbar dropdown dissapears even I am only on 3/5 menu
topbar has default z-index:12, if I change it above z-index of navbar, navbar stops working again
I have added css for topbar